# How to dump BIOS from running Sun Blade 1500?

Tags: bios, sun, sunos, ultrasparc

I'd like to replace an old-aged **Sun Blade 1500 Red** running **SunOS 5.8** by a Qemu-based Virtual Machine. Tutorials like [this](http://www.pawdata.com/gs/index.php?id=sparc-solaris-emulator) describe how to do this with older hardware, but as I need to run SPARC64 binaries I don't have the sources for, it has to be something newer.

The problem is that I need some BIOS for booting with `qemu-system-sparc64`, and I could only find one for SPARCstation 5.

**Is there a way of dumping the BIOS of the running machine, or extracting it offline somehow?**

I already thought of OpenBIOS, but couldn't come up with a SPARC64 cross compiler.

Comment: No idea if it's supported, but did you check out flashrom?